# Travis-ci unable to find the chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, travis-ci

I am trying to run my test on java/selenium test on travis-ci. But it seems like travis-ci is unable to find the chromedriver from my `src/test/resource` folder.  I have push the chromedriver along with the  testcases on github but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the error snapshot-

[image: Travis CI unable to find chromedriver]

Here is my t.travis.yml file -

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: java
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
jdk:
 - oraclejdk8

addons:
  chrome: stable

before_install:
 - wget -N 
 - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    /2.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
 - unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
 - rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
 - sudo mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/share/
 - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/share/chromedriver
 - sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver 
   /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
 - sleep 3

# whitelist
 branches:
   - first-branch    

 script:
   - whereis google-chrome-stable
   - whereis chromedriver
   - mvn clean install
```

Here's is how I am setting driver path in my test scripts:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
      System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
      "//src//test//resources//chromedriver");
```

Need help. is it the OS. I am running on OSx locally and linux container on travis-ci.

Update:  pushed linux version of chromedriver. It has started detecting the chromedriver but now it has thrown the following error:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to 
start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 
(6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-101- 
 generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace 
information)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to have xvfb started on a display port. Chrome on linux needs it.  Add the following code in your before-install stage/step.sleep is there to give some time for xvfb to start.

```
before-install:
  - "export DISPLAY=99:0"
  - "sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start"
  - sleep 3
```